# SQLite in Android - How to generate User IDs with date and sequential number per day

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I currently have an app where I store user data in a SQLite database, and one of my fields is a User ID.  I would like to add an option to auto-generate User IDs in an mmddyyXXX format, where XXX is a sequential number per user that resets every day.

Does anyone know how I would approach this?  I looked at some of the other similar questions, but they don't seem to be helpful.

Comment: 4/10/2018344 this what you need? where 344  is the a sequential number??am i correct?@Pink Jazz

Comment: Search for the largest ID that begins with that mmddyy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not complicated at all. If your'e similar with SQLite in android just take the `date` and the `userId` using a `SELECT` and generate that string yourself.

If the `XXX` is not the `userId` just save another table containing 'tokens' for users. every `userId` would have a 'token'.

Every new day just change the contents of this table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a TRIGGER that will generate the userid when a row is inserted.

The following may suit :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS newuserid AFTER INSERT ON users
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET userid = strftime('%m%d',date('now'))||substr(strftime('%Y',date('now')),3)||
        (           
        SELECT CAST(substr('000',1,3-length(count()+1)) AS TEXT)||CAST((count()+1) AS TEXT) 
        FROM USERS 
        WHERE substr(userid,1,6) = strftime('%m%d',date('now'))||substr(strftime('%Y',date('now')),3)
        )
    WHERE userid IS NULL;
END;
```

- The trigger is named newuserid
- userid is the column for the auto-generated id. The above relies upon it being NULL so it cannot be a PRIMARY INDEX.
- There is no reliance upon other columns.

#### Testing

Starting with an empty table :-

[image]

Inserting 4 rows using `INSERT INTO users VALUES(null,'This is a new user');` results in :-

[image]

To check for another date the rows are adjusted from 041018??? to 040918??? as per :-

[image]

4 more rows are inserted using `INSERT INTO users VALUES(null,'This is a new user');`, resulting in :-

[image]

---

#### Note this answer isn't intended to be fail-safe but rather the basis of the concept for the answer.